# Proper way of returning 302 with location

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openid-connect

I need to return correct redirect per specification of openID [Standard](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_oidc_auth_endpoint.html) but I have never worked with redirects so I'm not sure If I'm doing it right:

First way is as per [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward) :

```
@GetMapping("/redirectWithRedirectView")
public RedirectView redirectWithUsingRedirectView(RedirectAttributes attributes, @RequestParam String response_type, @RequestParam String client_id,
                                                      @RequestParam String redirect_uri, @RequestParam String scope, @RequestParam String state,
                                                      @RequestParam String nonce) {


        attributes.addFlashAttribute("flashAttribute", "redirectWithRedirectView");
        attributes.addAttribute("attribute", "redirectWithRedirectView");
        //do something
        String code = "SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA"; //in real case it is generated.
        return new RedirectView(String.format("%s?%s&%s", redirect_uri, code, state));
```

but call here returns

> argument type mismatch\nController [em_is_resource.EmIntegrationController]\nMethod [public org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView em_is_resource.EmIntegrationController.redirectWithUsingRedirectView(org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)] with argument values:\n [0] [type=org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareConcurrentModel] [value={}]

and second approach is

```
@GetMapping("/redir")
public Mono<String> redir(@RequestParam String response_type, @RequestParam String client_id,
                          @RequestParam String redirect_uri, @RequestParam String scope, @RequestParam String state,
                          @RequestParam String nonce) {
    String code = "SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA";
    return Mono.just(String.format("redirect:%s?code=%s&state=%s", redirect_uri, code, state));
}
```

but according to Postman request it returns just "redirect:https://server.example.com:8020/oidcclient/redirect/client01?code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA&state=af0ifjsldkj"

Is it correct or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 403 is request denied.  4xx range is for client errors.  3xx is for redirect.  Consider using the redirect range to send a redirect.

Comment: @DwB Thanks. I wrote wrong number. I meant **302 found**. I fixed my question